# Across languages that have adjectives, what are the most common grammatical inflections for adjectives?

Tags: morphology, linguistic-typology, adjectives, word-classes

Not all languages have adjectives;   some use adjectival nouns ("red.one" instead of "red") and/or stative verbs ("be.red" instead of "red").

Among languages that have adjectives, not all allow comparison of adjectives, and not all adjectives take agreement suffixes.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective

What I haven't been able to find on the Net is which kind of inflections for adjectives are the most common across languages that have a word class of adjectives that is morphologically distinct from, say, genitives and relative clauses.   No inflections?  Inflection for comparison?  Agreement?  Something else?

Comment: Mark Baker's excellent book 'The Syntax of Agreement and Concord' would be a good place to look on this. From what i remember, it's extremely rare for adjectives to agree in 1st/2nd person.